# Thunderbird: Hide unneeded fields in message-reader dialog

Tags: thunderbird

TB 24.1.1 for Windows message-reader shows bad/unneeded fields. I don't need them. Can i hide em somehow from dialog? Red mark--

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the CompactHeader plugin to see if it will let you minimize the header area.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/compactheader/?src=search